# Как НЕ выводить сообщения в консоль от system()?

Tags: c++, windows, командная-строка

У меня  есть код `system("taskkill /f /im program.exe");` (который убивает программу, ну это и так понятно). Так вот, после запуска этой команды, в консоль выводит сообщение (об удаче или неудаче). Как убрать эти сообщения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто...

```
system("taskkill /f /im program.exe >nul 2>&1");
```

Перенаправляем весь вывод на стандартный вывод в "никуда", а весь вывод на стандартный поток сообщений об ошибках — на стандартный вывод.

`system()` — это просто вызов командного интерпретатора, так что здесь все, как в обычной командной строке операционной системы.

Comment: Плюсы тут в полной мере ни при чем, это работа с возможностями командной строки в операционной системе. Когда-то целые игры .bat-файлами писали... :)